# i've created a button inside php. i want to call a function on click of that button

Tags: javascript, php, html

i have an html button inside a php ...

```
echo"<td width=14% align=center><input type=button value=Export onclick=mybtn3() /></td>";
```

this button is made inside php. now i want to call this function mybtn3(); 
i have tried defining this function in head and also in body. but onclick of that button , this function isn't calling. how to call this function and where to define it.

NOTE: in the body phase. there are many if else condition, each if condition produces new table. and at the end of every table i've defined this button. so that table may give new results depending upon the condition but this button will be there at the end of every table. so plz help how to call this button and where to define it.

THank you

`

Comment: please provide the code for mybtn3() function

Comment: I think it should be like this onclick="mybtn3()" with double quote . whole code should be :- `echo '<td width=14% align=center><input type=button value=Export onclick="mybtn3()" /></td>';`  
-and you should provide your function . 
I assume it's JavaScript function because you cant call PHP function inside HTML unless you use AJAX or DOM functions –

Comment: lets just say i want to echo something whenever the function calls. php won't allow me to echo html code with double quotes.

Answer (score 0):

use the below code, i recommend you to put this script in the header tag of your html document, even though you can put it at other places also, function mybtn3 will be called once you click on that button:

```
<script>

function mybtn3()
{
//your function code here
}

</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

To echo text with double quotes, use `\"`, or place it outside of the `<?php ?>`. Or better yet, use single quotes.

Answer (score 0):

Change to this:

```
       onclick=\"mybtn3()\"
```

\ works as an escape charachter